# Hide a link if user signed in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make it so if the user is signed in (using Devise) the "sign up" button in the navbar is hidden.

I was able to use

```
<%= if user_signed_in? %> <%= link_to etc.. %>
```

but I can't seem to get the write code to hide a button. I know there must be an else statement as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

example

```
<%- if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to t('auth.sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete' %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to t('auth.sign_in'), new_user_session_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to t('auth.sign_up'), new_user_registration_path %></li>
<% end %>
```